# Integer class in Java and its usability with operators

Tags: java, operators

Java has a class called `Integer` that is commonly used to wrap the primitive type `int` when declaring data structures, etc. When using this class to wrap `int` you can (as far as I understand) treat the elements you get from the data structure as type `int`.

For example, if I have the following code it would run properly

```
// size of ArrayList
int n = 5;

//declaring ArrayList with initial size n
ArrayList<Integer> arrli = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);

//Appending the new element at the end of the list
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        arrli.add(i);

int result = arrli.get(1) + arrli.get(2);
```

and `result` would have the value `3` as expected.

My question is how is this actually implemented under the hood? Java has no mechanism for overriding operators, etc so how does Java cleverly know how to treat the class `Integer` in this way?

Comment: This should be sufficient to understand how it works: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html.  If you need a deeper understanding, the linguistic "mechanisms" are described in detail in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: The mechanism is called **auto** boxing. You are not adding up Integer objects. The compiler secretly inserts the required code to turn Integer objects into int values, and these get added.